# dart's print method only takes one argument

Tags: dart

I am trying to print my output to the console, but whenever I do that I get this error, only when I pass it two arguments
Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found. print(nums,experiment); ^.

```
  void main() {

    List<int>nums = [2,7,11,15];

    nums.addAll([5]);

    var experiment = 9;


    print(nums,experiment);
```

}
Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
print(nums,experiment);
^

Comment: I don't even think this works in any language I have seen.. you have to either add `experiment` to the list or print them both as strings as done in the answer.

Comment: You've not seen Perl or Python or Ruby or ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `print` function only accept one argument, so you should pass those parameters as a string:

```
    print("$nums,$experiment");
```

The `nums` is a list so you can do this:

```
print("${nums[1]},$experiment");
```